# Creating a Service Area with 6 hours Travel Time on ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, network, service-area

I am creating a series of Service Areas using the built in networking features on ArcGIS Online. I need to create an area with 1 hour intervals for 6 hours of travel time. The issue is that ArcGIS Online does not allow for any longer than 5 hours through the online networking tool, and unfortunately I need that 6th hour!

I realize I may be out of options for accurate analysis, so I have moved on to other methods to try and at least show an approximate 6th hour. Buffering the largest area does not work as it returns a smooth area that just doesn't look good at all. I have tried creating a copy of the 5th hour, and using the Stretch Proportionally tool in my edit vertices, but this does not work well either.

I was hoping to get a couple more ideas I could try, because I am not sure what other options I have.

Comment: You have tags for ArcGIS Desktop and the ArcGIS Network Analyst extension but are you using those or just ArcGIS Online?

Comment: I am using desktop to try create a 6th hour for my service area, and I am using the network tools within ArcGIS Online.  So I guess the network analyst tag can be removed.  My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You could try picking a few points at the edge of the 5th hour and run them to create a one hour at each, and afterwards append the two together.  It's not perfect but it will give you the look (non buffered) you want.

Comment: This did work somewhat well, however I am using ArcGIS Online and my service area covers about 6 U.S. States, so in order to run it accurately I needed to use quite a few of the points around the area.  I think this one process used about 240 credits, which is definitely not something I can do all the time!

Comment: Glad that helped.  The credit thing is an issue though